# How to stop nbinfiniteList after loading complete data?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, nebular

Here I am facing some problems while using nbInfiniteList. Moreover all data has been loaded but nbInfiniteList can't be disabled?

```
<nb-list nbInfiniteList listenWindowScroll [threshold]="100" (bottomThreshold)="fetchData()" class="list-item"></nb-list>
```

How to disable bottomThreshold after data is finished?